# IF conditional not working with Relationship fields in Fluids

Tags: relationships, conditionals, fluid-field

When using a **Relationship** field with a **Fluid** field type the **current_field_name** variable can be printed out for debugging just fine, but **IF conditionals don't work** when using current_field_name.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="testfluid" dynamic="no" show_future_entries="yes" limit="1"}
    {testfluid}
    debug print out {testfluid:current_field_name}
    {if testfluid:current_field_name=="my_relationship_field_name_as_printed_out_fine_one_line_before"}
        #anything here never gets processed
        {content}
            {content:title}
        {/content}
    {/if}
    {/testfluid}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Also tried wrapping testfluid:current_field_name in braces, no change.

Just to be clear: if I remove the IF condition the relationship field is processed just fine, it's just the IF conditional not working. That wouldn't be an issue if one was only using a Fluid with one field, but obviously causes trouble with multiple different field types within a fluid.

Using latest EE version (6.2.4).

Comment: Have you noted the conditional isn't closed?

Comment: Ooops, just a typo, thanks, fixed (original code does have the closing IF)

Comment: Have you tried on a clean template? I had issues before with tags opened on other parts of the template that I forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 {if '{testfluid:current_field_name}' == '{my_relationship_field_name_as_printed_out_fine_one_line_before}'}
```

Comment: That's what I referred to by "Also tried wrapping testfluid:current_field_name in braces, no change."